# Combine Name and number save fix amount

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am troubled with a little code. I am reading a CSV file by adding a column and chanching the delimiter.

That works all perfect.

But, for the column where I want to give in the name, I am stuck on a problem.

When I add the column, I want to fill in the name: l_panoramic_000000 and I want to keep on giving it numbers, but within the 6 digits. Like this:

Some examples (of course numbering trough, but for the example skipt some).
l_panoramic_000000
l_panoramic_000001
l_panoramic_000010
l_panoramic_009523

--

Now it does it like:
l_panoramic_0000001
l_panoramic_0000002
l_panoramic_0000004
l_panoramic_00000010
l_panoramic_000000125
l_panoramic_0000002568
etc

How can I fix it to keep it in the 6 digits?

```
for incsv in folder_in.iterdir():
    outcsv = folder_out.joinpath('0new'+incsv.name)

    with open(str(incsv), 'rb') as input, open(str(outcsv), 'wb') as output:
        reader = csv.reader(input, delimiter = ',')
        writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter = ';')

        all = []
        row = next(reader)
        row.insert(0, 'L_panoramic')
        all.append(row)
        for k, row in enumerate(reader):
            all.append(['l_panoramic_000000'+str(k+0)] + row)
        writer.writerows(all)
```

With the code:

```
  for k, row in enumerate(reader):
        all.append(['l_panoramic_'+str.format(k+'06')] + row)
        writer.writerows(all)
```

it gives me:

```
 File "C:/code/convert/ConvertImageTrigger.py", line 20, in <module>
    all.append(['l_panoramic_'+str.format(k+'06')] + row)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the builtin [`format()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) function, e.g.:

```
'l_panoramic_' + format(k, '06')
```

will pad `k` with `0`s up to a width of `6`.
Alternatively, you can use `str.format()` with a similar format string:

```
'l_panoramic_{:06}'.format(k)
```

Comment: See correct usage above, it's not `str.format()` (that is the second form) and it is not `+` but a `,`.

Comment: Hi, ok: sorry fixed it. But it is now generating files of 2+ GB. So from 500 kb, to 2+ GB. Why is that?

Comment: Insufficient information to help you on that, there is no reason that swapping your current string with this string to create the difference in size.

Comment: When I open a file, it writes every row from 000000 - 000006 and than add's the header. and starts again with 000000 - 000006

Comment: I start with a file of 2307 rows, the result is 2662277 rows.

Comment: It does 1 line, and starts again, is does 2 lines and starts again, and 3 lines and starts again, and so on. With 2307 combinations, it keeps on going untill the end.

Comment: fixed it, sorry my mistake. The last code line was 1 tab in, writerows(all) so it was writing it over and over. Thnx! AChampoin, this fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to perform addition math operation over strings:

```
all.append(['l_panoramic_%s' % str(1000000 + k).replace('1', '', 1) + row)
```

Comment: Hi Raunak, with you code it is building CSV file in the 2 GB, whom are original 500 kb or so?